# In vb2005.net is there a function that works like the php function "htmlentities"

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0

In VB 2005 .Net is there a function that works like the php function "[htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)` is fairly similar.  However, it does not handle single quotes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) is the close thing that what you are looking for.
You will need other functions to do other stuff that htmlEntities does.